# How can I create a UIView that takes up the whole screens and gives a 'dimming' effect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I have a Slide Out view on my main screen.

When the user taps the `UIBarButtonItem` in the top left of the Navigation Bar, the main view 'slides' to the right to make partial room on screen for a `UIView` that slides in from the left of the screen.

When this happens, I would like to make my main `UIViewController`'s view 'dim'.

In code, how can I create a `UIView` that's the size of the entire screen, lay it over top of everything, and give it a 'dimming effect'.

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
UIView *dimmedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
dimmedView.opaque = NO;
dimmedView.alpha = 0.5;
dimmedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:dimmedView];
[self.view layoutSubviews];
```

I'm fairly new with creating UIView's in code, so I'm not sure exactly how to do it.

Comment: Can you print out the view's size w/ an `NSLog()`?

Comment: Your code looks alright, self.view should be dimmed with 0.5 alpha black. The Slide Out view system may use a snapshot view in place of self.view (whatever that is). Try adding the dimmedView view before launching the slide out transition.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `UIViewController` and animate that view controller on screen using a custom animation object. This was introduced in the iOS 7 custom view controller transitioning API. This will provide you with the functionality you are looking for of a dimmed background with the presented view controller on screen. Implementing this API is quite confusing at first, but once you get the hang of it, it is a breeze and very fun. There are many tutorials that show you how to use this functionality.

Here are several tutorials that I recommend:

[iOS 7 Custom View Controller Transitions and Rotation, making it all
   work](http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/ios-7-custom-view-controller-transitions-and-rotation-making-it-all-work)

[Custom UIViewController Transitions](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/)

[View Controller Transitions](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html)

[How To Make A View Controller Transition Animation Like in the Ping
   App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86521/how-to-make-a-view-controller-transition-animation-like-in-the-ping-app)

Also, if you are a member of the iOS Developer Program you can watch WWDC 2013 Custom Transitions Using View Controllers. As always Apple provides their documentation regarding custom view controller transitioning, but it seems to be across various APIs. I couldn't find an Apple programming guide that specifically dealt with custom view controller transitioning, so I would definitely use those tutorials above as a starting point before you dive in the documentation.